# How to address multiple targets from dependency list by one rule?

Tags: syntax, makefile, wildcard

I've the following example of `Makefile`:

```
all: foo1.gz foo2.gz bar1.gz bar2.gz
  @echo Done.

foo1.gz:
  touch foo1 && gzip foo1

foo2.gz:
  touch foo2 && gzip foo2

bar1.gz:
  touch bar1 && gzip bar1

bar2.gz:
  touch bar2 && gzip bar2
```

which aims to create and gzip certain files. This isn't the problem for small amount of files, but when you've hundreds of them, you don't want to specify each file as a dependency for given target.

So I would like to simplify the above syntax by specifying only one dependency, instead of for each file.

Therefore I would expect the syntax like:

```
all: %.gz
```

which should match multiple targets, however it doesn't work and it fails with:

> make: *** No rule to make target `%.gz`, needed by `all'.  Stop.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make some files and zip them. One way or another, you've got
to tell `make` what they are, or how to work out what they are.

A pattern rule can't do that. A rule is a pattern rule if and only if there
is exactly one `%` in its *target* side. See [10.5 Defining and Redefining Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html). So

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

is a pattern rule, and so is

```
%.xyz: foobar
    cp -f $< $@
```

They tell you that if some target matches the lefthand side %-wise, with *part* matching `%`, then that target
has the prerequisites that result from replacing `%` with *part* throughout the righthand side,
and the recipe for that target is the recipe in the pattern rule.

They *don't* tell you that anything *is* a target, and anyhow:

```
all: %.gz
```

isn't a pattern rule, per definition. With no `%` on the left, it's just a plain
old rule that says the target `all` has the prerequisite `%.gz`.

Broadly you've got two ways to let `make` know some list of filenames you want it to
deal with:

Spell them out, e.g:

```
files = foo1 foo2 bar1 bar2 ...
```

Or tell `make` some way to compute them, e.g.

```
files = $(wildcard ...) # `make` globbing
files = $(shell ....) # shell filter
```

See [8.2 Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions)
and  [8.3 Functions for File Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#File-Name-Functions)
for documentation of `make`s builtin resources for computing lists of filenames (or lists of strings, more generally).

Once you've picked a way for `make` to identify the files you want created and zipped,
*then* you can economize code with a pattern rule, e.g:

**Makefile**

```
zips := foo1.gz foo2.gz bar1.gz bar2.gz

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(zips)
    @echo Done.

%.gz:
    touch $(basename $@) && gzip $(basename $@)

clean:
    rm -f $(zips)
```